# HTML+CSS Multiple style, line text on a picture

Tags: html, css, image, text, line

In my last question I asked how could I add text onto the gray area of the picture, some guys suggested using `<span>`, I ended up with all the text (because it is a span after all, inline) on top of each other in a single line (left picture), even though it was set to `display:block`. How can I break it into seperate lines as seen in the picture on the right?
and does it make sense using h4/h5 for the styling or I should use different div's or something?

[image] [image]

HTML:

```
<div class="rightCol1"> 

    <a href="#"><img src="pic1.png"><span><h4>2014 02 16</h4><h5>po pirmojo etapo <br> naudingiausi - osvaldas <br> sarpalius ir lukas  šukutis</h5></span></a> 

    <a href="#"><img src="pic2.png"><span><h4>2014 02 16</h4><h5>geriausias sezono <br> startas per visą klubo <br> istoriją </h5></span></a>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rightCol1{
        float:right;
        margin-right:150px;
        margin-top:10px;

    }   

    .rightCol1 a {
        background:green;
        display: block;
        position:relative;
        height:200px;
        width:100px;
        margin-bottom: 160px
    }

    .rightCol1 a span {

        line-height:0px;
        display:block;
        margin-left:15px;
        width:234px;
        height:70px;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:-80;
        left:0;
        z-index:1;

    }

    h4{ 
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        font-style:;
        color:#e6540c;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:14;
    }

    h5{
        padding:0;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        color:rgb(193,193,193);

    }
```

Comment: Pretty much just kill your whole `.rightCol1 a span` rule.

Comment: But then: http://imgur.com/mgYOhoQ How can I vertically align it on top of the picture?

Comment: Remove the margin on your h5 element. That's what's pushing it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `span` has no line height, so each on the lines will come out ontop of each other. I suggest removing `line-height` from your `span` CSS:

```
.rightCol1 a span {
    display:block;
    margin-left:15px;
    width:234px;
    height:70px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-80px;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Lol, seriously? I swear I removed it like 4 times testing stuff, didn't seem to do anything. After I saw your post, removed it again and bam.. perfectly on top of the picture. Thanks ._.

Comment: @GytisK No problem, sometimes all it takes is a second pair of eyes